# JS Cheerio scraping dont work in node, but work fine in console on website

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am scraping some data from a webiste using cheerio.
I get the output I want in the console, but not in my node.

I am scraping the price on this website: https://www.coindesk.com/price/bitcoin-sv/

In the console, this is working:
`$('div[class="sc-bxivhb cNnmSt"] span[class="Typography__StyledTypography-sc-1xaoczh-0 euSZAS"]').textContent`

When I run it in the node I write: `$('div[class="sc-bxivhb cNnmSt"] span[class="Typography__StyledTypography-sc-1xaoczh-0 euSZAS"]').text()` but its not working.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

The page you are trying to scrape is generated with JavaScript. If you look into `view-source:https://www.coindesk.com/price/bitcoin-sv/` you will look mostly JavaScript and not so much HTML. `cheerio` cannot run JavaScript, it just parses static source code.

You need something like https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer to get JS-generated content.